# Does wearing a metal hat increase your chance of being struck by lightning?

Tags: electrostatics, electrical-resistance, lightning

Does wearing a metal hat does increase your chance of being struck by lightning?

Prompted by [this video](https://www.rt.com/viral/340505-lightning-strikes-video-panman/). My view is that it makes no difference as to the conductivity of the head or the field strength around the head during a thunderstorm. OTOH, would an insulating hat reduce the chance of being struck?

Comment: Related: [Does a lightning rod prevent lightning strikes?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65825/)

Answer (score 1):

Neither a metal nor an insulating hat will have any significant affect on the chance of a direct hit by lightning. According to the US National Weather Service ["Height, pointy shape, and isolation are the dominant factors controlling where a lightning bolt will strike."](https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-myths).

Metal objects objects close to the body may, however, increase injuries. A recent paper on ["Do metal objects such as mobile phones increase lightning risk?"](https://doi.org/10.1080/19475705.2021.1946172) estimated that the object would have to be many metres in size to increase the chance of a direct strike, but metal objects on the body or held in the hand could increase the chance of a side strike jumping to the person if lightning strikes a nearby object or an unsafe shelter. A lightning strike may also heat or even melt metal objects in contact with the body  and [cause burns](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32913440/) in addition to the direct lightning injuries.

Similarly, wearing insulating footwear offers no protection whatsoever against a direct lightning strike, but [may offer some protection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/571284/145491) from [ground currents](https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-science-ground-currents) from nearby lightning strikes.  As recommended by the [Naked Scientists](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=1dcfguksv39bd4o70evl9on4v0&topic=82616.msg645748#msg645748), however, the best footwear when lightning is nearby is probably running shoes, so you can get to the nearest safe shelter - [a substantial building or fully-enclosed vehicle](https://lightning.org/is-your-shelter-from-the-storm-a-lightning-safe-place-reminders-about-the-dangers-of-tents-and-thunderstorms/) - as fast as possible.